# Film about a young woman hired to tend to gifted children kept underground

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think I watched this 4-5 years ago on Netflix. The protagonist is a young woman, probably somewhere in her 20s or 30s who gets a job at a facility (government?) where they're doing something with gifted children that involves them being kept in an underground complex controlled by a computer system. I think I remember a sequence showing her having to traverse multiple corridors and elevators to get to the facility. As I recall it, the children are oddly quiet and passive. Early in the film, while in the facility overnight, she runs into some of the children, who seem to be sleepwalking, with the marketing suggesting that the children are going to turn out to be evil. I don't think I wound up watching much further than that, but I remember looking the film up at the time and finding out that the children are later revealed to not be malevolent, but there is something else going on at the facility that's not good.

My memory is that the protagonist is Caucasian with long hair, and I think most of the children were Caucasian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[Let's Be Evil](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3655682/)*** (2016)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Be_Evil):

> *Let's Be Evil* is a 2016 British science fiction-horror film directed by Martin Owen and written by Elizabeth Morris, Martin Owen, and Jonathan Willis.

From a [review](https://www.backtothemovies.com/lets-be-evil-review/):

> Our story focuses on Jenny (Elizabeth Morris) who since witnessing her father’s death as a child has been looking after her sick mother but is in-need of expensive medication and is falling behind on due rent and bills. **She takes up a job as a childcare worker in a futuristic experiment that involves educating children with augmented reality glasses in a very high security underground facility.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The facility is run by a computer entity by the name of Arial who teaches the workers the use of the AR tech and the jobs they must undertake to supervise these children but all is not as it seems.**

Comment: Thank you. That looks like the right one.